# Powershell with GUI - Hyper- V VM creation - always freezing

Tags: c#, powershell, user-interface, virtual-machine

I've been working on a powershell script for a long time.

The script create a GUI window where users can set some parameters and then they able to create Virtual Machines from VM templates.

The process was always freezing after the New-SCVMTemplate command.

Do you have any idea why it happens?

I deleted our VMMServer from the source code and it contains some comments.

```
Function Create-VM ($ComputerName,$Description,$Temp,$OS) { 

    <#[CmdletBinding()]
    param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String]$Method = $MultipleComboBox.Text,
    [String]$ComputerName = $ComputerNameTextBox.Text,
    [String]$Description = $DescripTextBox.Text,
    [String]$Temp = $VMtempComboBox.Text,
    [String]$OS = $OSComboBox.text
    ) #>
 

 <#$Method = $MultipleComboBox.Text
 $ComputerName = $ComputerNameTextBox.Text
 $Description = $DescripTextBox.Text 
 $Temp = $VMtempComboBox.Text 
 $OS = $OSComboBox.text #>
 
 $Template = Get-SCVMTemplate -VMMServer "" | Where {$_.Name -eq $Temp}

 Write-Output $Template
 
 $AnswerFile = Get-Script -VMMServer "" | where {$_.SharePath -eq "\\""\SCVMM_Library\Answer Files\ws2016_localization.xml"}

 $OperatingSystem = Get-SCOperatingSystem -VMMServer "" | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $OS}
 
 Write-Output $OperatingSystem
 
 $JobGroupId01 = [Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
 $TemporaryTemplateName = "Temporary Template"+$JobGroupId01
 
 Write-Output $TemporaryTemplateName
 
 Write-Host "New-SCVMTemplate:"

 New-SCVMTemplate -Name $TemporaryTemplateName -EnableNestedVirtualization $false -Template $Template -JobGroup $JobGroupId01 -ComputerName $ComputerName -TimeZone 95 -GuiRunOnceCommands "c:\windows\script\scomagent.cmd", "c:\windows\script\sccm_agent\UnattandedSCCMClientInstall.cmd" -FullName "" -OrganizationName "" -AnswerFile $AnswerFile -MergeAnswerFile $false -OperatingSystem $OperatingSystem -UpdateManagementProfile $null

 
 Write-Host "Get-SCVMTemplate"

 
 $Template = Get-SCVMTemplate | where {$_.Name -eq $TemporaryTemplateName}

 $virtualMachineConfiguration = New-SCVMConfiguration -VMTemplate $Template -Name $ComputerName

 Write-Output $virtualMachineConfiguration

 #$StatusTextbox.Text = $virtualMachineConfiguration

 Set-SCVMConfiguration -VMConfiguration $virtualMachineConfiguration -ComputerName $ComputerName


$cloud = Get-SCCloud -Name "Delivery Team"
New-SCVirtualMachine -Name $ComputerName -VMConfiguration $virtualMachineConfiguration -Cloud $cloud -Description $Description -JobGroup $JobGroupId01 -ReturnImmediately -StartAction "NeverAutoTurnOnVM" -StopAction "SaveVM" -Owner "HUNGARY\$env:USERNAME"

}


#####################################GUI################################################

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[xml]$XAML = @"

<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"


        Title="VM Tool" Height="448" Width="461" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" Background="#FF8B8484" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0">

    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.652,0.498" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="442">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="67*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="155*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="16*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="19*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="144*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Name="VMTempComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,211,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="152" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="22" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="1" Width="0"/>
        <TextBox Name="ComputerNameTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,79,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="152" Height="20" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Label Name="ComputerNameLabel" Content="Computer Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.15,0.445" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="26" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
        <TextBox Name="DescripTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,119,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="153" RenderTransformOrigin="0.483,2.09" Height="68" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AcceptsReturn="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Label Name="DescripLabel" Content="Description" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.211,0.599" Width="76" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="26" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
        <Label Name="VMTempLabel" Content="VM Template" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="28,188,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="89" Height="26" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
        <Label Name="OSLabel" Content="Operating System" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,237,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="26" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
        <ComboBox Name="OSComboBox" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,261,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="152" Height="22" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <Label Name="VMNumberLabel" Content="Number of VMs" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,286,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="100" FontWeight="SemiBold" Height="26"/>
        <TextBox Name="VMNumberTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,311,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151" Height="20" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="1"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="StatListBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Margin="154,35,10,60" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
        <Button Name="SaveButton" Content="Save VM" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,350,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.684,-0.223" Width="68" Height="22" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
        <Button Name="CreateButton1" Content="Create VM" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="49,350,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.684,-0.223" Width="68" IsCancel="True" Height="22" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
        <Label Name="MultipleLabel" Content="Single or Multiple?" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.349,0.014" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="116" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
        <ComboBox Name="MultipleComboBox" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" IsReadOnly="True" />

    </Grid>

</Window> 

"@

#Read XAML
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
#catch{Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader"; exit}
# Store Form Objects In PowerShell
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object {Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}


####ADD DATA###

$MultipleComboBoxItems = 'Single','Multiple'

foreach ($i in $MultipleComboBoxItems) {

    $MultipleComboBox.Items.Add($i) | Out-Null

}

$MultipleComboBox.Text = "Single"

$TemplateList = Get-SCVMTemplate | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "DT -*"} | Select Name | Sort-Object Name

foreach ($i in $TemplateList) {

    $VMtempComboBox.Items.Add($i.Name) | Out-Null

}

#$VMtempComboBox.text = "DT - WS2016 std - 2vCore 4GB RAM - APP-DEV-VID 1502"

$VMtempComboBox.add_MouseEnter({
    
    $VMtempComboBox.ToolTip = $VMtempComboBox.Text
})

$OStype = Get-SCOperatingSystem | Where-Object {($_.Name -like "Windows Server 201* Standard") -and ($_.Name -notlike "Windows Server 2012*")} | Select Name

foreach ($i in $OStype) {

    $OSComboBox.Items.Add($i.Name) | Out-Null

}

#$OSComboBox.Text = "Windows Server 2016 Standard"

$OSComboBox.add_MouseEnter({
    
    $OSComboBox.ToolTip = $OSComboBox.Text
})

$CreateButton1.Add_Click{(
    
    Create-VM -ComputerName $ComputerNameTextBox.Text -Description $DescripTextBox.Text -Temp $VMtempComboBox.Text -OS $OSComboBox.text
    #-Method $MultipleComboBox.Text #>

)}

$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Comment: Ok, here is my job:
 Start-Job -Name "New-Template" -ScriptBlock {
 
 New-SCVMTemplate -Name $using:TemporaryTemplateName -EnableNestedVirtualization $false -Template $using:Template -JobGroup $using:JobGroupId01 -ComputerName $using:ComputerName -TimeZone 95 -GuiRunOnceCommands "c:\windows\script\scomagent.cmd", "c:\windows\script\sccm_agent\UnattandedSCCMClientInstall.cmd" -FullName "" -OrganizationName "" -AnswerFile $using:AnswerFile -MergeAnswerFile $false -OperatingSystem $using:OperatingSystem -UpdateManagementProfile $null
 
 } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob

Comment: I got this error:

Cannot bind parameter 'VMTemplate'. Cannot convert the "DT - WS2016 std - 2vCore 4GB RAM - APP-DEV-VID 1502" value of type "Deserialized.Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.Template" to type "Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.Template".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-SCVMTemplate], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.Cmdlets.NewTemplateCmdlet
    + PSComputerName        : localhost

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon